# Avoid ESLint import/no-unresolved error when import package without main in package.json

Tags: typescript, import, eslint

ESLint does not resolve some specific package paths. It can recognized the others, and TypeScript compiler can all.

I found the packages does not have `main` field in their `package.json`. They have only `type` fields.

For instance,

`src/index.tsx`:

```js
import { Node } from '@react-types/shared';
```

Run command:

```sh
$ npx eslint src/index.tsx 

/my-project/src/index.tsx
  1:22  error  Unable to resolve path to module '@react-types/shared'  import/no-unresolved

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

[The package's `package.json`](https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum/blob/%40react-types/shared%403.6.0/packages/@react-types/shared/package.json):

```json
{
  "name": "@react-types/shared",
  "version": "3.6.0",
  "description": "Spectrum UI components in React",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "types": "src/index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  }
}
```

As a workaround, I could use `// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved`.

Is there a way to avoid this error properly?